# Python: How do I show list with > 1 variable as separate columns in pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am using pandas to present some data.

1) My `x_test` variable is a list with 2 variables, and I want to present both variables in separate columns in the data frame. I used the below code, but I get `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`.

```
'x': x_test[1].flatten(),
'2x': x_test[2].flatten(),
```

2) How do I restrict to 2 decimal places for "Prediction Diff" column in my data frame?

3) I tried sorting my data frame by "Prediction Diff" column, but it is not correctly sorted.

The whole code is following.

```
import pandas as pd
x_test = list()
x_test = test_data[[input_param_name, input2_param_name]].values

test_predictions_table = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x_test[1].flatten(),
    '2x': x_test[2].flatten(),
    'y': y_test.flatten(),
    'Predicted y': test_predictions.flatten(),
    'Prediction Diff': (y_test - test_predictions).flatten()
})

test_predictions_table.sort_values(by='Prediction Diff')
print(test_predictions_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have few notes for you.

1. When you call `.values` on pandas.DataFrame, in other words, you make a list of rows, which is not your case. According to your code, you want to make a list of columns. Personally, I would leave this approach and make a data frame from existing data frame `test_data` with [`pandas.DataFrame.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method.
2. To round column to two decimals, use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function.
3. When you want to sort your data frame values by a column, you have to assign the result to a variable. Otherwise, the result is not applied.

Your code could look like this:

```
# make a copy of test_data columns
test_predictions_table = test_data[[input_param_name, input2_param_name]].copy()

# make new columns and round 'Prediction Diff' column
test_predictions_table['y'] = y_test
test_predictions_table['Predicted y'] = test_predictions
test_predictions_table['Prediction Diff'] = round(test_predictions_table['y'] - test_predictions_table['Predicted y'], 2)

# sort test_predictions_table data frame by 'Prediction Diff' column
test_predictions_table = test_predictions_table.sort_values(by='Prediction Diff')
```